# Expose Java Library to .NetCore2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, ikvm

I'm upgrading to .NetCore2.2 from .NetFramework4.7.2 and there is legacy code that uses a java library that I would like to continue using after the conversion (I would prefer to not change this library).

While using .NetFramework I used [IKVM](https://www.ikvm.net/) to execute this library, but it is unavailable in .NetCore, and I haven't found alternatives that work in .NetCore.

So far I've only tried [jni4net](http://jni4net.com/) as I have not found anything else to look at.

Is there a way to use this java library in .NetCore, or can anyone suggest an alternative way to consume it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a heads up: .NET Core 2.0 was End-of-Life'd last year: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/86

Comment: Thanks @OmairMajid, I chose .NetCore2.0 because I wanted to use the lowest version that worked, but .NetCore2.2 would also be fine and I'll update the post.

Comment: For such legacy code, your current only option is to stick to .NET Framework, using IKMV or J#. Microsoft promises Java interop only in .NET 5 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/ so there is still a year to go.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

JNBridgePro works with .NET Core, but it's .NET Core 3.0.